# After update to Android 9, moto g6 vibrates on home button press even though vibrations turned off

Tags: updates, vibration

My phone just updated and now every time i press the home button i get a vibration. How do i turn off vibrations?

[image]
here's a photo of my vibration settings.

Comment: Do you use "One Button Nav" to replace the "Back, Home, Recent" buttons? Please read your user manual; it mentions haptic feedback as part of this mechanism.

Comment: I do not use one button navigation.